# Extracting unique food type from dataframe column and visualise,

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, visualization, spacy

I'm having difficulties converting columns to object then extracting food categories and then visualise to bar graphs and pie charts.

The dataframe column is follows:

```
0      NaN                     Burgers, American, Sandwiches           $   
1      NaN  Coffee and Tea, Breakfast and Brunch, Bubble Tea         NaN   
2      NaN        American, Cheesesteak, Sandwiches, Alcohol           $   
3      NaN                                             Pizza           $   
4     22.0         Breakfast and Brunch, Burgers, Sandwiches         NaN
```

When trying to use this:

```
ue_df_c['food_type']=ue_df_c.astype('object')
stop= stopwords.words('english')
ue_df_c['food_type']=ue_df_c['food_type'].apply(lambda x:"".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in stop))
print(ue_df_c['food_type'].head())
```

I get

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

What am I doing wrong? How do  I proceed after this to visualise as pie charts and bar charts the unique values in food_type for e.g burgers,sandwiches, bubble tea etc?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question and provide a small reproducible example. From your text I cannot understand if "Burgers, American, Sandwiches" (first row) are in the same cell or in different columns of the same row. Furthermore, if you have a messy dataset, simply removing stopwords is unlikely to standardise everything, for example "Coffee and Tea" would become "Coffee Tea" (which is not a type of Tea but two separate items), whereas "Bubble Tea" is a type of tea. What if you encounter a plural (e.g. "Teas") or a spelling variation ("cheesesteak" vs "cheese steak")?